# Implementing a single thread server/daemon (Python)

Tags: python, sockets, server, daemon

I am developing a server (daemon).

The server has one "worker thread". The worker thread runs a queue of commands. When the queue is empty, the worker thread is paused (but does not exit, because it should preserve certain state in memory). To have exactly one copy of the state in memory, I need to run all time exactly one (not several and not zero) worker thread.

Requests are added to the end of this queue when a client connects to a Unix socket and sends a command.

After the command is issued, it is added to the queue of commands of the worker thread. After it is added to the queue, the server replies something like "OK". There should be not a long pause between server receiving a command and it "OK" reply. However, running commands in the queue may take some time.

The main "work" of the worker thread is split into small (taking relatively little time) chunks. Between chunks, the worker thread inspects ("eats" and empties) the queue and continues to work based on the data extracted from the queue.

How to implement this server/daemon in Python?

Comment: Can I ask why it needs to be a single thread? 

What would be broken if you had a thread that would listen to messages from the socket and reply immediately "ok" to the client. You would then have a Queue between the listener and worker, and the listener would just dispatch messages to this queue. They would be processed in order of arrival and the worker thread should have its "state in memory" preserved and not messed by any other thread or process.

Comment: @Hannu I insist that I need single **worker** thread. To have another thread for socket listening is OK.

Comment: Shouldn't a socket listener thread and a Queue then solve your problem? 

Your socket would always accept new messages, they would be responded immediately, the worker would preserve its state and requests would be processed in the order of their arrival? Your worker can then "eat" tasks from the queue as it sees fit.

Comment: @Hannu Thanks for the idea. I will research it (maybe tomorrow). Could you give more details about your idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a sample code with internet sockets, easily replaced with unix domain sockets. It takes whatever you write to the socket, passes it as a "command" to worker, responds OK as soon as it has queued the command. The single worker simulates a lengthy task with sleep(30).  You can queue as many tasks as you want, receive OK immediately and every 30 seconds, your worker prints a command from the queue.

```
import Queue, threading, socket
from time import sleep

class worker(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self,q):
        super(worker,self).__init__()
        self.qu = q

    def run(self):
        while True:
            new_task=self.qu.get(True)
            print new_task
            i=0
            while i < 10:
                print "working ..."
                sleep(1)
                i += 1
                try:
                    another_task=self.qu.get(False)
                    print another_task
                except Queue.Empty:
                    pass          

task_queue = Queue.Queue()
w = worker(task_queue)
w.daemon = True
w.start()

sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
sock.bind(('localhost', 4200))
sock.listen(1)
try:
    while True:
        conn, addr = sock.accept()
        data = conn.recv(32)
        task_queue.put(data)
        conn.sendall("OK")
        conn.close()
except:
    sock.close()
```

Comment: Thanks you very much, but your code seems not to allow the worker to inspect the queue in the middle of the task. (I remind that in my (edited) question the work of the worker is split into small chunks between which it inspects the queue.)

Comment: Or is it easy? I have not yet read it very carefully, as I have also another job

Comment: I've modified the code to include checking of the queue while "working". get(False) does not block if the queue is empty, it just raises Queue.Empty, which is promptly ignored.

Comment: After some more thinking, I concluded that on the request I should not just print "OK", but first do some quick computations (and after this reply either OK or ERROR) and these computations should be in the worker thread (or be synchronized with the worker thread) so that they don't run simultaneously with an another operation in worker thread, but run serialized in order. I'd like to see the modified code (but don't delete what you've already wrote!) Excuse me for you doing a work for me, but I'd like to see the modified code (among the old version of code which should not be removed)

Comment: Note that in the previous comment I assume that the computations replying to a request should **not** start before the current "small chunk" of the worker thread finishes